# Multiple publishing hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink

I have a sharepoint library that reuqires 3 different Publishing hyperlink columns to different documents, I went to ' add from existing site columns' and added one publishing hyperlink, however after the single one is inserted i cannot add anymore from that location. I still neeed to add 2 more, anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

The site column you used is an out-of-the-box default site column. All you have to do is go to **Site Settings** > **Site Columns** and create 2 more site columns. Then go back to your list and add them the same way you added the first one.